# Declare static, constant member in abstract base class, assign it to a value in derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, constants

I have an abstract base class and a pair of classes derived from this base class. I would like to introduce a `static const` member that has a different value between the two derived classes but the same value for all instances of a given derived class.

I have code which uses a base class pointer assigned to an instance of one of the two derived classes so that I can easily switch between derived classes by changing what the base class pointer is assigned to. I would like to be able to obtain the value of the derived class' constant value using the base class in a similar way so that I can easily switch between the two classes. The desired behavior looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Abstract base class
class A {
    protected:
    int c; // this is really a constant and should also be static
    public:
    static int s;
    int get_c() const {
        return this->c;
    }
    virtual int foo() = 0; // makes this class abstract
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    static const int sb = 10;
    B() {
        this->c = 1;
    }
    int foo() {
        return -1;
    }
};

class C : public A {
    public:
    static const int sc = 20;
    C() {
        this->c = 2;
    }
    int foo() {
        return -2;
    }
};

int main() {
    B btest;
    C ctest;

    A *ptr = &btest; // pointer to instance of B
    //cout << ptr->c << endl; // would fail compilation (c is protected)
    cout << "B's c = " << ptr->get_c() << endl;
    cout << "B's foo() returns " << ptr->foo() << endl;
    cout << "Accessing B's static const member: " << B::sb << endl;

    ptr = &ctest; // pointer to instance of C
    //cout << ptr->c << endl; // would fail compilation (c is protected)
    cout << "C's c = " << ptr->get_c() << endl;
    cout << "C's foo() returns " << ptr->foo() << endl;
    cout << "Accessing C's static const member: " << C::sc << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code `sb` and `sc` are the `static const` members I want, but the problem with them is that base class `A` has no knowledge of them. The base class member `c` is doing what I want but is not `static const` as desired (I've made `c` a `protected` member so that it cannot be modified, but if I can declare it `const` then it can be `public`). This code has the desired behavior from `c`:

1. I can get a distinct value for `c` from each derived class using a base class pointer.
2. `c` is effectively constant since it is `protected` and I provide no setter function.

However, `c` isn't *really* constant in that it isn't `const` and it isn't `static` so every instance has an unnecessary copy of it.

Is there a way to get the desired behavior and also declare `c` with `static const` like `sb` and `sc`?

Comment: I don't understand the question, if you want a distinct value for c for each derivation then it cannot be static.  If it needs to be modified then it cant be const.  If the concern is just access , cant you just make it private in the base class and provide a public getter/setter where necessary?  Can you rephrase into a specific question if this is not what you meant?

Comment: It does not need to be modified, and it is the same value for every instance of a given derived class. But it is a different value for each different derived class.

Comment: this sounds like an X/Y problem. Can you tell us why you need this?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid

Comment: @Borgleader The derived classes each implement a communication protocol. I want to store `static const` values for how long writes and reads take, which differs between protocols.

Comment: If it needs to be a different value for each derived class it would necessitate a different location in memory and thus cannot be static.  You could make it a template class and have different values for each derivation but they would not really be the same base class. Mike's answer gets as close as you can, either use the virtual dispatch with constant return types if you dont want to store it, or you will need to store that variable in an instance specific variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't implement this with a static variable in `A`; that will be common to all subtypes of `A`, so you can't get a different value for each subtype. Since the dynamic type of the object behind a base-class pointer is only known at run-time, you'll need a run-time mechanism to get the value from it.

This could use a per-object variable, which can be `const` if you initialise it in the constructor:

```
class A {
    // ...
    const int c;
    A(int c) : c(c) {}
};

class B : public A {
    // ...
    B() : A(1) {}
};

class C : public A {
    // ...
    C() : A(2) {}
};
```

or a virtual function that each subclass overrides to return a different value:

```
class A {
    // ...
    int get_c() const = 0;
};

class B : public A {
    // ...
    int get_c() const {return 1;}
};

class C : public A {
    // ...
    int get_c() const {return 2;}
};
```

Both options meet both your requirements; one has the cost of a virtual function call on access, while the other has the cost of a per-object variable. You'll have to decide which cost is more suitable for your needs.

Comment: Yes, that would work. I just seems like a function call simply to return a value that is known at compile time and never changes is pointless overhead.

Comment: @Null: It's not known at compile time, since it depends on the runtime type of the object it's called on.

Comment: Good point. I was thinking it's known at compile time since I only assign the base class pointer to an instance of one of the two derived classes -- if I switch to a different derived class I modify the source and recompile. I only have a few instances of the derived classes so I think the `const` member method is better for my purposes -- the extra space requirement is not a big deal. Thanks.